# Ideas to Implement a Game Center Module on Exsisting Web Application

Tags: php, node.js, codeigniter, websocket, socket.io

I have a CodeIgniter MVC web application which works perfectly. Recently, my client asked me to add a game center module to this web application which we can add game modules as we develop them and, the first game they want to add is a backgammon.

So the game center itself is basically a new controller in exsisting MVC application, so that both game center and mvc application can share the same user session.

But for the backgammon module, which approach should I use?

My ideas:

- A node.js application to achieve peer-to-peer connection between users.
- A flash or Java / Javascript based backgammon game which can communicate with the node server.
- A Flash game, which uses Adobe's Cirrus (http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/) to allow P2P game experience.
- A php web service like module to handle various requests from game client (in this method, game client can be written in anything)

Considering all the game modules must have a user to user chat module, which approach should I choose? What are the pros / cons of these methods, or, any other method I couldn't think of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A flash application for the front end, since it is installed in most computers and the behavior is the same in all browsers (compared to Javascript, where you would have to adapt your UI and logic to each browser's JS implementation).

A Node.JS backend for peer to peer. You can even use RTMFP (check out ArcusNode or other p2p node.js implementations).